# How to simulate java socket connection break?

Tags: java

I have written java application that makes socket connections with a legacy system.

How can I simulate the connection failure *(Eg Socket connection timeout, read timeout, network failure)*, so that i can add necessary code based on the exception trace ?

Comment: Go back to previous questions and accept answers by selecting the tick on the left hand side.  Ideally, since you asked a simple and concise question, you will have a some acceptable answers.  You can add comments when the answers need clarification.

Comment: Sniffy can do it http://sniffy.io/docs/latest/#_testing_bad_connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mock framework such as Mockito or EasyMock, mock a Socket object.

Look at the Javadoc for Socket and make your mocked object fail at some point with an Exception thrown by it in your unit tests.

Comment: Well i am trying with Mockito. Let me check and come back

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to trigger an actual failure or test your code works in different situations?

If its the latter, I would create a simple mock server, or if this is not practical, a proxy server.  Close the outbound or incoming connection, or stop sending data at a certain point.  At this point you can test your code behaves as expected.